# How to make CSS flex-box take only as much space as needed?

Tags: html, css

To get an understanding of layout structure, this is my HTML and CSS code respectively:

```css
.course-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: max-content;
  background-color: #eef6f0;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.course-list {
  width: max-content;
  height: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: auto;
}

.course-item {
  width: 340px;
  height: 370px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="course-container">
  <div class="course-list">
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I noticed that course-list is taking more width than is needed for displaying items. I want the course-list to have a margin such that it is centered inside the course-container, horizontally, and the course-items inside the course-list to be left-aligned.

This is what the output looks like right now. `[ ]` represents individual course-item, and dashes `-` represent spaces through either margins, padding or gaps, in course-container or course-layout.

```
-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]------
-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]------
-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]------
-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]------
-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]----------
```

However, I want the the structure to be like the following:

```
---[ ]-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]---
---[ ]-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]---
---[ ]-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]---
---[ ]-[ ]-[ ]-[ ]---
---[ ]-[ ]-[ ]-------
```

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**
Temani Afif correctly marked this question as duplicate, and the solution on that question works perfect.

Comment: Remove display: flex; from .course-container.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `media-queries` and containers similar to that in what Bootstrap uses.

You can read here on the documentation: [Containers - Bootstrap v5.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/).

You'll have to specify container widths for all screen sizes for maximum responsiveness.

```css
body {
  background-color: #eef6f0;
}

.course-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: max-content;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.course-list {
  width: max-content;
  height: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: auto;
}

.course-item {
  width: 340px;
  height: 370px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .course-container {
    width: 1400px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="course-container">
  <div class="course-list">
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
    <div class="course-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That solves my problem, but is not there a more elegant way? I will wait a bit to see if there is a better solution, otherwise I will mark your answer as correct. Either way, THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR HELP :)